# Separability of Stochastic Volatility Model

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-volatility, heath-jarrow-morton

After having read the article of Trolle & Schwartz regarding their general stochastic volatility term structure model (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=966364), it is not clear how the model becomes Markovian. It is well-known that if and only if HJM model is Markovian, then the forward rate volatility is separable in time i.e.
$$\sigma_f(t,T)=h(t)g(T),$$
where g and h is a deterministic vector function and matrix process respectively. However the specification in the article is
$$\sigma_f(t,T)=(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1(T-t))e^{\gamma(T-t)},$$
which I don't see satisfies the representation from above. I'm getting stuck rewriting here
$$\sigma_f(t,T) = (\alpha_0 + \alpha_1)e^{-\gamma T}e^{\gamma t} - \alpha_1 e^{-\gamma T}e^{\gamma t} t,$$
as it not possible to take the last term on the RHS underneath the parenthesis due to the "t".

Hope you can help clarify.